# Get the number of subscribers to a channel in Pubnub

Tags: pubnub

Is there a way to get the number of subscribers subscribed to a specific CHANNEL in Pubnub?

If so, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Presence - Here Now

Read all the [docs about Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/overview) to get a base understanding of what it offers.

The [`hereNow` API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/presence) is what seek. If you need code sample for another language, you can navigate to the other SDKs (languages) on the docs site.

The old school `callback` way:

```js
pubnub.hereNow(
  {
    channels: ["chats.room1", "chats.room2"],
    includeState: true
  },
  function (status, response) {
    console.log(status, response);
  }
);
```

The `async/await` way:

```js
async function getChannelOccupants {
    try {
        const result = await pubnub.hereNow({
            channels: ["chats.room1", "chats.room2"],
        });
    } 
    catch (status) {
        console.log(status);
    }
}
```